# Render image from audio

Tags: javascript, html, soundmanager2

Is there a possibility to render an visualization of an audio file?

Maybe with SoundManager2 / Canvas / HTML5 Audio?
Do you know some technics?

I want to create something like this:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your new abbreviation for "something" - "sth." is overused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't possible yet except by fetching the audio as binary data and unpacking the MP3 (not JavaScript's forte), or *maybe* by using Java or Flash to extract the bits of information you need (it seems possible but it also seems like more headache than I personally would want to take on).

But you might be interested in [Dave Humphrey's audio experiments](http://vocamus.net/dave/?p=974), which include some cool visualization stuff. He's doing this by making modifications to the browser source code and recompiling it, so this is obviously not a realistic solution for you. But those experiments could lead to new features being added to the `<audio>` element in the future.

Comment: Update :  webAudio , mozAudio and projects like JS-Mad allow this to happen this ... even in browsers which can't support it. Infact with some crazy polyfilling jsMad can decode audio in back uber-old browsers like IE

Answer (score 6):

You have a tone of samples and tutorials here : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/#webaudio

For the moment it work in the last Chrome and the last last Firefox (Opera ?).

Demos : http://www.chromeexperiments.com/tag/audio/

To do it now, for all visitors of a web site, you can check SoundManagerV2.js who pass through a flash "proxy" to access audio data http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/ (They already work on the HTML5 audio engine, to release it as soon as majors browsers implement it)

Up to you for drawing in a canvas 3 differents audio data : WaveForm, Equalizer and Peak.

```
soundManager.defaultOptions.whileplaying = function() { // AUDIO analyzer !!!
    $document.trigger({ // DISPATCH ALL DATA RELATIVE TO AUDIO STREAM // AUDIO ANALYZER 
        type             : 'musicLoader:whileplaying',
        sound            : {
            position         : this.position,          // In milliseconds
            duration         : this.duration,
            waveformDataLeft : this.waveformData.left, // Array of 256 floating-point (three decimal place) values from -1 to 1
            waveformDataRight: this.waveformData.right,
            eqDataLeft       : this.eqData.left,       // Containing two arrays of 256 floating-point (three decimal place) values from 0 to 1
            eqDataRight      : this.eqData.right,      // ... , the result of an FFT on the waveform data. Can be used to draw a spectrum (frequency range)
            peakDataLeft     : this.peakData.left,     // Floating-point values ranging from 0 to 1, indicating "peak" (volume) level
            peakDataRight    : this.peakData.right
        }
    });
};
```

With HTML5 you can get :

```
var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
var timeByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
function onaudioprocess() {
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(timeByteData);
    /* draw your canvas */
}
```

Time to work ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run samples through an FFT, and then display the energy within a given range of frequencies as the height of the graph at a given point. You'll normally want the frequency ranges going from around 20 Hz at the left to roughly the sampling rate/2 at the right (or 20 KHz if the sampling rate exceeds 40 KHz).

I'm not so sure about doing this in JavaScript though. Don't get me wrong: JavaScript is perfectly capable of implementing an FFT -- but I'm not at all sure about doing it in real time. OTOH, for user viewing, you can get by with around 5-10 updates per second, which is likely to be a considerably easier target to reach. For example, 20 ms of samples updated every 200 ms might be halfway reasonable to hope for, though I certainly can't guarantee that you'll be able to keep up with that.

Answer (score 0):

http://ajaxian.com/archives/amazing-audio-sampling-in-javascript-with-firefox

Check out the source code to see how they're visualizing the audio

Answer (score -1):

For this you would need to do a Fourier transform (look for FFT) which will be slow in javascript, and not possible in realtime at present.

If you really want to do this in the browser, I would suggest doing it in java/silverlight, since they deliver the fastest number crunching speed in the browser.